# How can I query data from multi tables in a single query, including "like" data based on user login

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have three tables for streaming data from database

```
stream_master
    stream_id
    user_id -> foreign Key
    stream_title
    stream_content

user
    user_id
    user_name
    password


stream_likes
    stream_like_id
    stream_id
    user_id
```

I can join together to get data stream, but I want to get "stream_likes" data for each "stream_master" rows, based on user(Logged in) activity. Mean if user already like stream get 1 for each row

Is this possible to execute in single query ?

my output should be :

```
[stream_id => 10,
user_id => 10015,
stream_title=>"title of stream",
stream_content="stream content",
stream_like=>1],
[stream_id => 10,
user_id => 10018,
stream_title=>"title of stream222",
stream_content="stream content22",
stream_like=>0]
```

I am not able to find a nice solution for this. Could someone can help me on this?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m.*, IF(l.stream_like_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS stream_like
FROM stream_master m
LEFT JOIN stream_likes l
ON m.stream_id = l.stream_id AND m.user_id = l.user_id
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: thank your for your solution,

But here how to implement Logged-in users part with query, I have user_id of the logged-in user.

I have implemented by adding user login details at if condition, but its returning expected result.

SELECT m.*, IF(l.stream_like_id IS NOT NULL AND l.u_id=$USER->UID, 1, 0) AS stream_like FROM stream_master m
LEFT JOIN stream_likes l
ON m.stream_id = l.stream_id AND m.user_id = l.user_id